# Solidity functions naming order

Tags: solidity, conventions

The only documented convention about naming the functions in smart contracts seems to be that it should be camelCase.

The order of subjects and actions seems to be arbitrary unless I'm missing something.

For me it sounds logical to place the main topic/subject first and then some actions/descriptors.

Example - ERC721 contract from OpenZeppelin has the following functions:

```
beforeTokenTransfer
afterTokenTransfer
```

```
isApprovedForAll
getApproved
setApprovalForAll
```

I would call it:

```
tokenTransferBefore
tokenTransferAfter
```

```
approvalForAllStatus 
approvalGet
approvalSetForAll
```

Maybe it's not so clear in the above example but when writing some custom functions I'm really inclined to put the main keyword first.

For example, for the functions to manage trustees:

```
trusteesAdd
trusteesRemove
```

instead of:

```
addTrustee
removeTrustee
```

that most people seem to be doing.

My reasoning it's more logical and easier to understand the function purpose if the main keyword goes first.

Also in case functions get sorted alphabetically, for example in some auto-generated documentation reference, it will keep the related functions next to each other.

Thoughts? Where am I wrong in my thinking? Should I follow the common style or is it fine to keep doing what I've been doing for my own code?

Comment: IMHO `addTrustee` is easier to read than `trusteesAdd` for an English speaking person. The rest are easily solvable with a good IDE.

Comment: Maybe this is more something for the Solidity forum: https://forum.soliditylang.org/

Comment: Thank you all for your comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you're wrong thinking that way, but at first sight for me, it seems like `addTrustee` is better than `trusteesAdd` because is easier to read. I mean, the verb before already says to me what the function is going to do, and trustees just tells me what or who is suffering the action that add is.

I do think that semantically speaking, it makes more sense that the verb comes first, since for example, we speak "I'll add you as my friend" and not "I'll friend add you". Although your suggestion still is legible, for me at least it seems like `beforeTransferToken` is easier to understand when reading code than `tokenTransferBefore`.